# SSD overheating Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssd, overheating

My SSD M2 disc (ADATA SU800NS38) have almost all the time 60ºC and sometimes temperature reach even 75ºC.

If my memory is good this problem isn't occur in Windows system but i might be wrong.

Laptop have 5 moth (MSI GL62 6QC)

What can be cause it any ideas?

Comment: Is there a lot of disk I/O going on in the background?

Comment: No.  I checked it via iotop and it some around 0-3%.

Comment: Aren't these normal temperatures (just a few minutes before seeing this question I saw smartd attribute changes in my journal, yes I have it open most of the time)? What are the temperatures under Windows and what is the problem with the temperatures reaching this threshold? Does the system become unstable or anything? Please also tell us the exact S.M.A.R.T attribute name, you might either be reading it wrong or there is an offset from the actual value.

Comment: No as i red normal temperature under pressure is some around 40C. I don't know what is tempereture on windows because i dont have this impaired system xd but as i remember laptop was cool not like now... If it comes  about stability its okay, laptop works perfectly fast and stable. I used sensors program.